# MySQL-How to select first duplicate row of corresponding column value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains three columns(A,B,C). All columns are of datatype varchar().Here i want to select only those initial rows which is first duplicate value of column A. Like column A has distinct value (1,2,3) so the initial row that has value 1 in column A need to be retrieved.one more thing i don't have a timestamp column in my dataset.

```
For value 1 in column A, i need to retrieve row that has 1,2,1 value for column (A,B,C)
For value 2 in column A, i need to retrieve row that has 2,4,1 value for column (A,B,C)
For value 3 in column A, i need to retrieve row that has 3,1,1 value for column (A,B,C)

A|B|C
-----  
1|2|1
3|1|2
3|3|1
2|4|1
3|1|2
3|1|4
1|2|3

Now i want a Output Table as describe below.

A|B|C
-----
1|2|1
3|1|2
2|4|1
```

Comment: @Sebas Please help me here

Comment: You have no 'time' in your column, so there's no 'first' time.

Comment: @Kunal2229 you have to define what you mean by first. Is it arbitrary or depending on other columns?

Comment: @Sebas Here First is ,suppose like column A has 1 two times so i want first value 1 of column A and want all other values of column also along with it. as you can see the 2 table , first table is Input and second table is output after applying such Query .

Comment: @Strawberry i have huge dataset where it contains timestamp column but here i can't present my dataset so i gave just sample things so that you can understand it easily.

Comment: So you have a timestamp. Then the problem is trivial (assuming 'first' means 'the one with the earliest timestamp'). Show us the timestamp.

Comment: @Sebas can you help me on this and have you understand what i exactly want from INPUT table(first table defines above)

Comment: if some data is essential to a problem we should be provided with that data.

Comment: @Strawberry but still i am confused how to retrieve based timestamp and yes all rows are arranged in earliest timestamp

Comment: @Sebas can you tell me how can i do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following. For simplicity, I'm using an auto_incrementing id but a unique timestamp would work just as well...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table 
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,A INT NOT NULL
 ,B INT NOT NULL
 ,C INT NOT NULL 
 ,UNIQUE(a,b,c)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c) VALUES
 (1 ,2 ,1),
 (1 ,1 ,2),
 (2 ,3 ,1),
 (2 ,4 ,1),
 (3 ,1 ,2),
 (3 ,1 ,4),
 (3 ,2 ,3);

 SELECT x.* FROM my_table x ORDER BY id;
 +----+---+---+---+
 | id | A | B | C |
 +----+---+---+---+
 |  1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
 |  2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
 |  3 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
 |  4 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
 |  5 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
 |  6 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
 |  7 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
 +----+---+---+---+

 SELECT x.* 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT a
             , MIN(id) min_id 
          FROM my_table 
         GROUP 
            BY a
      ) y 
     ON y.a = x.a 
    AND y.min_id = x.id 
  ORDER 
     BY id;
 +----+---+---+---+
 | id | A | B | C |
 +----+---+---+---+
 |  1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
 |  3 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
 |  5 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
 +----+---+---+---+
```

For more information on this soution, see the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping me here with your solution , i really thankful