# Mysql Query select one row from the same values (select duplicate only)

Tags: mysql

I have duplicate data on my table as described bellow.

```
no  name    adrress
1   Joe     No.3
2   Joe     No.2
3   Joe     No.1
4   Anna    No.4
5   Anna    No.5
6   Ali     No.6
```

I want to show only the first item from duplicate data like bellow.

```
  no  name    address  
  1   Joe     No.3
  2   Anna    No.4
```

Comment: `select * from table_name order by no limit 1` if this is not what you are looking at describe more about the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really should take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand what we expect from our users and their posts.  Please [edit] your question to add your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to find the duplicate only, this one similar to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000671/mysql-how-to-select-first-duplicate-row-of-corresponding-column-value)

for your case will be like this

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM new_table x 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT name
             , MIN(id) as min_id , COUNT(id) as count_id
          FROM new_table 
         GROUP 
            BY name
      ) y 
     ON y.name = x.name 
    AND y.min_id = x.id 
    AND y.count_id > 1 
  ORDER 
     BY id;
```

hope that answer your question.

Comment: I forgot about this issue, but that's work. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("select * from $table where id='1';");
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be lot of answers to this question see which one fits your requirements:

```
Select * from tablename where no=1;

Select * from tablename where adrress LIKE "%3%";

Select * from tablename ORDER BY no LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for selecting particular row in the table

> select * from yourtablename WHERE primarykeyfield=" ";